# How to parse this table and extract data from it?

Tags: php

I have the following table: http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=lat

It is a currency exchange list and I need to extract some data from it. On left side of the table are currency ID numbers. Would it be possible to extract data from specified rows based on their IDs?

For example, from the table above, I want to extract currencies with IDs 978, 203, and 348.

Output should be:

- EUR 104,2182
- CZK 4,2747
- HUF 38,7919

By looking at similar examples here, I came up with this: http://pastebin.com/hFZs1H7C

I need somehow to detect IDs and the print proper values... I'm noob when it comes to programming and I need your help.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=lat');

$dom = new domDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
                foreach ($cols as $col) {

                                echo $col;

                }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 12):

Collecting the table data as array for later usage:

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=lat');

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// collect header names
$headerNames = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//table[@id="index:srednjiKursLista"]//th') as $node) {
    $headerNames[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

// collect data
$data = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//tbody[@id="index:srednjiKursLista:tbody_element"]/tr') as $node) {
    $rowData = array();
    foreach ($xpath->query('td', $node) as $cell) {
        $rowData[] = $cell->nodeValue;
    }

    $data[] = array_combine($headerNames, $rowData);
}

print_r($data);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ŠIFRA VALUTE] => 978
            [NAZIV ZEMLJE] => EMU
            [OZNAKA VALUTE] => EUR
            [VAŽI ZA] => 1
            [SREDNJI KURS] => 104,2182
        )

    ...
)
```

Example usage:

```
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    printf(
        '%s %s' . PHP_EOL,
        $entry['OZNAKA VALUTE'],
        $entry['SREDNJI KURS']
    );
}
```

Comment: Great great great!!!
Works perfect, I have added second array with currency codes, then compare this two arrays and create table with fancy country icons :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use xpath and domdocument features of PHP to extract specific data from html(or xml.)

```
$src = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$src->formatOutput = true;
$src->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=lat");
@$src->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($src);
$values=$xpath->query('//td[ contains (@class, "tableCell") ]');
foreach($values as $value)
{
echo $value->nodeValue."<br />";
}
```

this will print innerHTML of every td element with class="tableCell".