# How to parse HTML table using PHP? 

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

I need to fetch the second column of the given HTML table using PHP. How can I do it?

**References:**

Table to be parsed: http://bit.ly/Ak2xay

HTML code of this table: http://bit.ly/ACdLMn

Comment: yes, and get an array of columns

Comment: @everyone who marked this as a duplicate... I don't see anything about parsing html TABLES on that page. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For tidy HTML codes, one of the parsing approach can be DOM. DOM divides your HTML code into objects and then allows you to call the desired object and its values/tag name etc.

The official documentation of PHP HTML DOM parsing is available at http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

For finding the values of second column for the given table following DOM implementation can be done:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://mytemporalbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/code.txt');

$dom = new domDocument;

@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');

$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        echo $cols[2];
}

?>
```

**Reference:** Customized the code provided at [How to parse this table and extract data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818335/how-to-parse-this-table-and-extract-data-from-it) to match this question's demand.

Comment: Would this be in the same file as the code where you want to implement and use this data?

Answer (score 1):

Using phpQuery http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ you could do

```
$file = LINK OR NAME OF YOUR FILE
phpQuery::newDocumentFile($file);
$data = pq('UNIQUE COLUMN ID OR CLASS AS YOU WOULD FOR CSS ex: .class #id')->html();

echo $data.
```