# Parse HTML table into array with PHP- get image attributes

Tags: php, html, xpath, attributes, domdocument

I'm trying to parse a table from an HTML webpage, but I'm having trouble.

Here is what my HTML approximately looks like :

```
<tbody>

<tr class="even">
<td class="time">Monday 20:10</td>
<td class="place">Paris 14</td>
</tr>

<tr class="odd">
<td class="time">Monday 21:00</td>
<td class="place">Paris 13</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

EDIT : Here is my PHP

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.gymsuedoise.com/loc/dt/?id=64';


$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0", // something like Firefox 
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
);

$curl = curl_init($url); curl_setopt_array( $curl, $options ); $content = curl_exec($curl); curl_close($curl);
$dom = new DOMDocument(); @$dom->loadHTML($content); $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); 

$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody'); 
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) 
{ 

$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 

$date = $cols->item(0)->nodeValue; $liste_element[$i]['date'] = trim($date);
$intensite = $cols->item(2)->nodeValue; $liste_element[$i]['intensite'] = trim($intensite);
$animateur = $cols->item(3)->nodeValue; $liste_element[$i]['animateur'] = trim($animateur);
$forfait = $cols->item(5)->nodeValue; $liste_element[$i]['forfait'] = trim($forfait);

$i++;
} 

echo '<pre>';            
print_r ($liste_element);
echo '<pre>';            

?>
```

My issue is that my script can't scrape anything in the 6th column (i.e. `item(5)`) of the table, as there are only pictures and no text. 
How could I scrape the content in the `alt` or `title` attribute if the the `<img>` tag ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse HTML table using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816194/how-to-parse-html-table-using-php)

Comment: I tried the code suggested in that answer but I get a 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object`.

Comment: I edited my question. The issue was related to a security message from the server of the website which was considering my script as a malware.

Comment: To get the attribute value (alt, title or any other) use attributes property, like this: $nodeList->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem("alt")->nodeValue;

Answer (score 2):

The error that you are getting is from printing/echoing an object.
Also you can't give a URL as an argument for loadHtml.
You would need to do:

```
$fetchHtml = file_get_contents($html);
$html = $dom->loadHTML($fetchHtml);
```

But doing it that way you are going to run into some issues with whoever's server you are tying to scrape.

What I did was used a open sources PHP packaged called [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/overview.html#installation).

You will need to install it in your directory using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).
To install composer just run:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Then open the composer.json file and put the following:

```
{
   "require": {
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"
   }
}
```

Then run:

```
composer update
```

This will create get all the dependencies you will need to run Guzzle.

If you are on shared hosting then download Guzzle and upload it to your server.

github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases

The new file will look like this:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$url = 'https://www.gymsuedoise.com/loc/dt/?id=64';

$res = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);


$html = (string)$res->getBody();


// The @ in front of $dom will suppress any warnings
$domHtml = @$dom->loadHTML($html);

  //discard white space 
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

  //the table by its tag name
  $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tbody');


  //get all rows from the table
  $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

  // loop over the table rows
  foreach ($rows as $row)
  {
   // get each column by tag name
      $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
   // echo the values  
      echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
      echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
      echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
    }


?>
```

Keep in mind that this will only extract the first table from the html.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my server is on a shared hosting service. To avoid this limitation, I tried to get the content of the page with `curl` and it's working.

Comment: If you have shared hosting without an ssh terminal no problem.

Comment: You can download guzzle from here and upload it yo your directory. [link](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases)

Comment: @Guillaume I updated my post for you. There are a lot of benefits using Guzzle and it is easy!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to utilize the method [DOMElement::getAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) on the image. To traverse the nodes down to the level of the image, utilize the [DOMNode::$firstchild](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.firstchild) property of both the node, and then the anchor tag. To ensure that the `$firstChild` won't be `NULL`, use [DOMNode::hasChildNodes()](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.haschildnodes.php).

```
if ($cols->item(5)->hasChildNodes()) {
    $anchor = $cols->item(5)->firstChild;
    if ($anchor->hasChildNodes()) {
        $altAttribute = $anchor->firstChild->getAttribute("alt"); 
        $liste_element[$i]['forfait'] = trim($altAttribute);
    }
}
```

For a demonstration, see [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/0U8F0Vv1Pt0JMnrf).