# Parse HTML table and extract data

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I found this topic:
[How to parse this table and extract data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818335/how-to-parse-this-table-and-extract-data-from-it)
Which probably is the answer for my problem, I want to the same thing - parse some external table, extract data and print this data on my webpage.
@Yoshi gives perfect answer, but when I trying to use this code, I am getting empty array

> Array ( )

I don't know why this doesn't work? I trying to use the same example

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=lat');

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// collect header names
$headerNames = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//table[@id="index:srednjiKursLista"]//th') as $node) {
    $headerNames[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

// collect data
$data = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//tbody[@id="index:srednjiKursLista:tbody_element"]/tr') as $node) {
    $rowData = array();
    foreach ($xpath->query('td', $node) as $cell) {
        $rowData[] = $cell->nodeValue;
    }

    $data[] = array_combine($headerNames, $rowData);
}

print_r($data);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server's error logs? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I don't have any error on server log
this tag doesn't gives me any errors

Answer (score 1):

Page has changed, that is why code is not working, this one works:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=lat');

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// collect header names
$headerNames = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//table[@id="index:srednjiKursLista"]//th') as $node) {
    $headerNames[] = $node->nodeValue;
}

// collect data
$data = array();
foreach ($xpath->query('//tbody[@id="index:srednjiKursList:tbody_element"]/tr') as $node) {
    $rowData = array();
    foreach ($xpath->query('td', $node) as $cell) {
        $rowData[] = $cell->nodeValue;
    }

    $data[] = array_combine($headerNames, $rowData);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Now, I suppose that you want to extract SREDNJI KURS value for some of the currencies, and you are going to do that

```
echo $data[15]['SREDNJI KURS'];
```

This is going to extract for USD.